# Custom angular directive that doesn't need a closing tag?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Writing an angular directive without transclusion, and limited as an element. Is there an option where it doesn't need to be closed?

```
<my-super-img attr="value">
```

Instead of

```
<my-super-img attr="value"></my-super-img>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all angular directives *must* have a closing tag.

I have previously [tried to do just this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6360)

In summary, the HTML specification does not allow for custom tags that are self closing.